# Open option not coming in IE for downloaded CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-5

Below is my code for CSV file download,

```
send_data get_csv(params), filename: filename, type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', disposition: 'attachment'
```

In Mozilla and Chrome after csv file download I am able to see (open-with, save) options so I can open my file without save.

But in IE I am getting only save option, there is no open option. Open gets enable when i will save the file, But I need need that option on download.

Anyone can suggest me, what I am missing here, Do I need to make any changes in my code side

Using Ruby(2.5) and Rails(5.2) versions.

Comment: This is a browser specific issue. It must be something to do with the settings of IE. See this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/ie11-no-download-prompt-always-tries-to-open/3c32d119-95ff-4614-a713-badd127a8c4a

Comment: Thanks @Pavan but the same thing working for my old version ruby on rails csv file with same version of IE.

Comment: IE uses Security zones. The file>Properties menu in IE will tell you which IE security zone your test/dev/or production website is mapped to. eg. if you system administrators disable downloads in the Internet zone, but the host maps to the Trusted zone, then blob data will not download. To correct the problem you need to add the word blob to your trusted sites list.

Comment: we need to know which IE security zone your dev/test/production environment is mapped to. When testing or debugging or trouble shooting, make sure you are using the default IE security zone settings. Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"... optionally you can use the Networking tab of the dev to inspect the response from the server or to step through breakpoints.